# Scoring a column with conditions in R using sd

Tags: r, statistics, aggregate, grouping

I'm an R/coding newbie. I want to assign a score to a column based on some conditions. I have some random data below, that helps explain my own data.

```
name    average score
a     -3.56714858     0
a     -0.41934072     0
a     -1.02200958     0
b      0.67713883     0
b      0.29228235     0
b      0.11338159     0
c     -1.48595572     0
c     -0.35328884     0
c     -1.26491347     0
d     -0.27093065     0
d     -0.14913264     0
```

What I want to do;

- If (name=a & average > 2sd of benchmark) then assign score= 2
- if (name=a & average < 2sd of benchmark) then assign score=0.5
- etc.

Edit: benchmark = average(of top 3 "a"), so I'm scoring the rest of the "a" based on how they compare to the top three, so how many standard deviations they lie from the top 3.

Each letter has its own benchmark or number that I am comparing it to. So I was manually going through, letter by letter, like:

```
df$score[df$name == "a"
                & df$average >= benchmark
                & df$average <  (benchmark + sd(benchmark)]<- 1
df$score[df$name == "a"
                & df$average >= (benchmark + sd(benchmark)
                & df$average < (benchmark+ 2sd(benchmark))]<- 2.0
df$score[df$name == "a"
                & df$average > (benchmark+ 2sd(benchmark))]<- 2.5
df$score[df$name == "a"
                & df$average < benchmark
                & df$average >= (benchmark - sd(benchmark)]<- 1
df$score[df$name == "a" 
                & df$average < (benchmark - sd(benchmark)
                & df$average >= (benchmark - 2sd(benchmark))]<- 0.5
df$score[df$name == "a" 
                & df$average < (benchmark - 2sd(benchmark))]<- 0
```

I have thousands of rows and more groups than the letters a-d. I'm hoping I can find a **faster** way to do this. My long method is also creating errors. Please help

I have the same scoring principle for each group, but the benchmark is different for each group.

Comment: Is there always one threshold for each group? And are there always two possible values for the outcome (greater than threshold or less than threshold)? Do those thresholds, and those above/below values, differ by group (letter)?

Comment: I have 6 scores for each group. Greater than average & less than 1sd of average, greater than 1sd of average and less than 2sd of average, and greater than 2sd of average, and vise versa. Each letter has its own metric for scoring, so even if the scoring idea is the same, they are all being compared to something different

Comment: could you share example thresholds for the a, b, c, d above, in the form you have it, such as a data frame? (Otherwise, to answer we would have to create our own version)

Comment: is `mycondition` a value or a list of values or what?

Comment: Just made an edit. I hope I made it clear now. Thanks

Comment: How are you calculating the `sd(benchmark)`? It seems that you have contradictory statements: the first benchmark you use in `df$score[df$name == "a"
                & df$average >= benchmark
                & df$average <  (benchmark + sd(benchmark)]<- 1` is a single value, and the benchmark you use in `sd(benchmark)` is a vector

Comment: benchmark = average(of top 3 "a"), so I'm scoring the rest of the "a" based on how they compare to the top three, so how many standard deviations they lie from the top 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would structure your problem this way: First you have your data frame, then you should also have another data frame, which we will call `bench`, with variables as "name", "benchmark", and "sd.benchmark". Something like that. Then I would

You can use `dplyr` package:

```
require(dplyr)

df.new <- left_join(df, bench, by = "name") %>%
          mutate(score = ifelse(average >= (benchmark - sd.benchmark) & average < (benchmark + sd.benchmark), 1, 
                         ifelse(average >= (benchmark + sd.benchmark) & average < (benchmark + 2*sd.benchmark), 2,
                         ifelse(average >= 2*sd.benchmark, 2.5, 
                         ifelse(average < (benchmark - sd.benchmark) & average >= (benchmark - 2* sd.benchmark), .5, 0)))))
```

The reason I have less conditions is because in your example *`benchmark - sd(benchmark)`* and *`benchmark + sd(benchmark)`* had the same value of 1 for conjoining ranges.

`left_join` combines `bench` to `df` using all values of `df`. It is like `merge(x,y, all.x = T)`. From the join, the steps are now passing data to the `mutate`. `mutate` creates a new variable based on the `ifelse` statements.